# I can't access the internet inside the pods of rancher running in centos

Tags: kubernetes, centos, rancher, centos8, firewalld

I'm running rancher in centos with the master node being the same machine.
I can do everything but when i try to "apt-get update" inside the pods i get:

```
 Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                   
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease         
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease           
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done        
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The problem is in the firewalld of centos because when i disable the firewall i have internet access inside the pods. I have already added the ports provided in this [link](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/resources/advanced/firewall/). But still i cant have access to the internet.
Is there another way without disabling the centos firewall?

I'm using Centos 8 and Rancher 2.

Comment: is your master node located locally? Please share your pod's manifest to look into

Comment: Thank you but I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it. The problem was in the docker not being able to resolve DNS queries inside containers. The work around was, first add the [ports](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.0-v2.4/en/installation/resources/advanced/firewall/) and then executing the following commands:

```
# Check what interface docker is using, e.g. 'docker0'
ip link show

# Check available firewalld zones, e.g. 'public'
sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones

# Check what zone the docker interface it bound to, most likely 'no zone' yet
sudo firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=docker0

# So add the 'docker0' interface to the 'public' zone. Changes will be visible only after firewalld reload
sudo nmcli connection modify docker0 connection.zone public

# Masquerading allows for docker ingress and egress (this is the juicy bit)
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
# Reload firewalld
sudo firewall-cmd –reload

# Reload dockerd
sudo systemctl restart docker
```